# Interaction with running programs on Microsoft's Windows or Unix

Tags: linux, posix

I'd like to create a program, which acts like a human in Telegram, WhatsUp or another messenger. I want this program to send messages, add contacts, click buttons etc. I've done it using an auto clicker, but pseudocode looks very bad and it's hard to rewrite or to add something.

Is there any way to do the same with Posix API (not only simulate mouse clicks but also check if the window is closed or open, full-screen or minimized, find text field add type text). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What windowing system: Are these apps for X11, browser, or other?

Comment: Is it pseudo code (pretend code), or real code? (edit questions to clarify)

Comment: Posix does not necessarily mandate a graphical window. Your best bet is curses.